# Speakers not detected or playing sound

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a question similar to the below, none of which solve my problem:

- [1. not detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775434/speakers-not-detected)
- [2. no sound from speakers](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2323498)
- [3. Tried this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure)
- [4. Also tried this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting)

I have [these speakers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00X741TKG). Here are the results to `aplay -l` and `lspci | grep -i audio`

```
:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: Generic Analog [Generic Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
:~$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a2f0
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

I've tried removing and reinstalling drivers:

```
# audio
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo dpkg -i Downloads/...
sudo apt-get install -f
# or remove / reinstall drivers
sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
sudo apt-get install gdm ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

Nothing is working so far--**so any help would be appreciated.** The speakers do play sound when plugged into my work laptop--a Macbook Pro--so I don't believe it's a hardware problem.

Output of `pacmd list-sinks`:

```
2 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 9050
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 21.94 ms
    max request: 4 KiB
    max rewind: 64 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 23.22 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
    module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "HDMI 0"
        alsa.id = "HDMI 0"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "7"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xf7080000 irq 17"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0be3"
        device.product.name = "High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.string = "hdmi:1,1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo-extra1"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)"
        device.description = "High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Nvidia GPU 0b HDMI/DP"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10de000b,10de0101,00100200"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                device.product.name = " "
    active port: <hdmi-output-1>
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.iec958-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 9958
    volume: front-left: 65531 / 100% / -0.00 dB,   front-right: 65531 / 100% / -0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 1
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
    card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "Generic Digital"
        alsa.id = "Generic Digital"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "1"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7340000 irq 133"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "a2f0"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "iec958:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "iec958-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (IEC958)"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958)"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek Generic"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec1220,1458a182,00100003"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:

    active port: <iec958-stereo-output>
```

Comment: As you did not mention it specifically, I will ask. Did you check the Volume Sliders in whatever audio GUI you now have? You could also use '$ pacmd list-sinks' to get that info from the system.

Comment: @WillemK Yes, I have adjusted the audio sliders both within Ubuntu and the manual knob on the speakers... As I mentioned, I *think* (not 100% since I'm still pretty new to Ubuntu) the problem is that the computer is not recognizing the speakers as being installed / plugged in.

Comment: What did the command 'pacmd list-sinks' show you? Google for pacmd examples, they can be helpfull.

Comment: @WillemK `packmd list-sinks` gives 2 sinks, one active one idle. both have volume and are not muted, seems pretty normal

Comment: is the active sink showing the speakers and/or headphones? I am thinking the output sink is somehow not linked to the active sink. I had something similar because i am using an usb soundbar and i need to direct outputting apps to the active sink.

Comment: i use a Chrome and select webradio station to play music. Then open Output Settings gui to 'visualize' the ouput. That way i am sure of a constant audio supply so i can use pacmd to play with the settings.

Comment: Alex, please edit your question and paste the output of `pacmd list-sinks`.

Comment: @WillemK done. The manufacturer has indicated (via email) the output is listed as my HDMI, and needs to be switched to internal device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved my problem:

`pacmd set-card-profile 1 output:analog-stereo`

from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398030/change-default-sound-device)

Comment: Just as i mentioned. Incorrect routing. Glad it works now.