# Speaker not detected

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my computer, dual booting it with Windows 10.

I have three speakers connected to my tower: the *monitor integrated* ones (really bad sound), a pair of *headphones* and an *Eldor Chopin ek1000krc*.

They all work on Windows, while the last of these (Eldor speakers) does not work on Ubuntu.

If I go under "Sound", it detects three output devices: two of them are the monitor and the headphones, while the third says "*Line Out - Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller*", so I have to guess that Ubuntu actually detects them, but no sound comes out (not even from the test).

Following bunch of guides and questions on forums (such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775434/speakers-not-detected)), I checked `alsamixer`, but every single entry is unmuted.

As far as I know, drivers are automatically managed on Ubuntu, so I would have little to do on that side...

Any suggestions?